# How to reduce tick rate of winforms timer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a simple game where animations are done using a timer. Timer rate is initially set to 200, but for every 1000 points player gets I want timer to get faster, so I thought I could just decrease the interval

```
if (score > 0 && score % 1000 == 0)
     {
         GameTimer.Interval -= 20;
     }
```

But when I reach score of 1000, winform crashes with following error on the line given above:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval. Interval must be greater than 0.
>   Parameter name: Interval

How can I correctly reduce the interval rate? (or make my program tick faster by any other means)

Edit: The code piece given above was placed inside the tick event, which caused if statement to execute several times

Comment: Note that decreasing the `Interval` _increases_ the rate, as the interval is in milliseconds; is that what you intend?

Comment: @Bizhan I am pretty sure it is set to 200 initially. The way I changed it was by editing the initial value (100) from timer properties menu in Form1.cs[Design] page

Comment: Yes I got that and deleted my comment. please see my answer below

Comment: @Ach113 I don't know the whole implementation, but I suppose you can have problems with this one in case player has 1000 points and you run this code a few times. So, be careful with when you run it.

Comment: Check whether `Interval` is <= 20. If it is, set it to 1 rather than `-= 20`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `GameTimer.Interval -= 20;`. Run the code. How many times does the breakpoint get hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that the Interval value has reached zero.

So these lines are executed several times until it crashes:

```
 if (score > 0 && score % 1000 == 0)
 {
     GameTimer.Interval -= 20;
 }
```

And that is because the condition is met in every interval after the timer passes the condition once.

Define your logic outside the timer code and you'll be fine:

```
 void Score(int value){

      score += value;
      if (score <= 0) return;

      if(score % 1000 == 0)
      {
          GameTimer.Interval -= 20;
          //if(GameTimer.Interval <= 0) I suppose level is already finished...
      }
 }
```

### edited

mjwills pointed out this issue that the interval still may hit zero. So you must write your code in a manner that eliminates this risk.

a non-linear reduction makes more sense in this case:

```
 void Score(int value){

      score += value;
      if (score <= 0) return;

      if(score % 1000 == 0)
      {
          GameTimer.Interval *= .9f;
          if(GameTimer.Interval <= 0) GameTimer.Interval = 1;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a risk that `Interval` will still reach 0 (albeit more slowly)?

Comment: @mjwills yes but I suppose OP has a limit in mind when setting these magic numbers. but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I suspect the OP has _not_ thought of that (in fact, it is more than a suspicion - we know they didn't since that is the reason they are seeing the exception to start with!). So it may be worthwhile tweaking the solution so as to protect him / her from shooting themselves in the foot. _You likely want to check the value **before** setting it, not after._

Comment: @Ach113 I added something to my answer that is worth considering.

Comment: @Bizhan, I just added another control to statement which checked that interval was greater than value by which I decreased it.

Comment: @Ach113 forgive me if I get a little bit off-topic here but (since this is a game) when you compare interval 200->180 with 40->20 the sudden change of speed is drastic in the last one where the speed suddenly doubles. but with a non-linear transition the change of speed is always have a same feeling.

Comment: @Bizhan I see, never thought about it, thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2):

The tick rate cannot be less than or equal to 0.

You could simply add an if statement to check that:

```
if (GameTimer.Interval <= 20) {
    GameTimer.Interval = 1;
} else {
    GameTimer.Interval -= 20;
}
```

However, this means that the timer interval will reach a limit after a certain score is reached. Also, the screen can't update that fast (1000 times a second). You should probably keep the frame rate at 30fps.

Therefore, to make the animation appear faster, do a larger proportion of the animation in each second. For example, to move something 1000 pixels to the right, don't move it 1 pixel every 1/1000 of a second. Instead, move it 50 pixels every 1/20 of a second.

From your comment:

> The issue is that I do not understand why interval is going below zero, the if statement is executed only once, and it immediately gives me that error.

Then you are executing the if statement more than once. My guess is that you are running it in the timer tick event handler. Once your score reaches a multiple of 1000, that if statement will be run every time the timer ticks, until your score changes.

To fix this, you can put the code in the setter of the score.

Answer (score 1):

the timer interval keep decrease until it reach to zero "0" that is your error

you can use

```
int x = (score/1000)*20  
if (x < 200)
    GameTimer.Interval = (200 - x);
```